# stl: добавить в вектор элемент и получить его итератор

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Подскажите, можно ли добавить в вектор элемент и получить итератор одной функцией или все таки придется делать так:

```
data.push_back(object);
auto it = data.begin() + (data.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С++11:

```
auto it{data.emplace(data.end(), object)};
```

Comment: Вопрос был о добавлении существующего объекта `object`, функция `emplace` тут подходит слабо так как требует лишнего копирования объекта.

Comment: @freim Что значит "не подходит"? Это рабочий код. Никакого лишнего копирования или создания ненужных промежуточных объектов тут не происходит (в отличие от функции `insert`).

Comment: а чем `emplace` от `Insert` в конец отличается?

Comment: @Zhihar Тем что `emplace` может создавать объекты на месте без промежуточных объектов и ненужного копирования. Проще говоря, передает аргументы прямо в конструктор добавляемого объекта. А `insert` принимает вторым аргументом ссылку на объект, при необходимости создавая временный объект, и затем копированием или перемещением создавая добавляемый объект в контейнере.

Comment: В данном случае `emplace` будет полностью эквивалентно `insert` - и там, и там будет вызываться конструктор копии. Работать, конечно, будет, но это нецелевое и вводящее в заблуждение использование функции. К тому же в случае `insert` можно использовать и перемещение - в отличие от `emplace`.

Comment: @VTT, т.е. можно так `it = data.emplace(data.end(), object)`, учитывая, что операция не однократная и нельзя в одну строчку объявление еще вклинить, оно выше

Comment: @freim: Что за ерунда? Функции `emplace` почти полностью замещают функции `push` и `insert`. В современнои коде надо стараться пользоваться именно `emplace`. Ничего нецелевого здесь нет - наоборот, именно так и надо. И `emplace` по определению полностью поддерживает перемещение. О каком "в отличие" вы ведете речь?

Comment: @AnT, "в современнои коде надо стараться пользоваться именно emplace" - откуда дровишки? Это официальная рекомендация, или чье-то личное мнение (Скотта Мейерса, например)? (насчет перемещения - да, поддерживается).

Comment: @freim: "Дровишики" вытекают из такого *объективного* факта, что функции `emplace` делают абсолютно все то же, что делают функции `insert` и `push`, но при этом не заставляют клиентский код выполнять обязательное создание промежуточного объекта. В такой ситуации нет никаких причин пользоваться функциями `insert` и `push`.

Comment: @AnT, никто и не спорит, что `emplace` надо использовать для случая, когда  использование `insert` влечет за собой создание промежуточного объекта. Но заменять все `insert` на `emplace` это, мягко говоря, странная рекомендация. Мейерс с этой рекомендацией, по большому счету, понимания не нашел.

Comment: @freim `insert` имеет смысл использовать вместо `emplace` только во вариантах, которые вставляют несколько элементов, потому что аналогичных перегрузок `emplace` нет. Во всех остальных случаях имеет смысл использовать именно `emplace`, как более гибкую и общую функцию. Более того, в реализациях стандартных библиотек есть тенденция реализовывать `push` и `insert` через вызов `emplace` во избежание дублирования, поэтому от их использования получится извлечь разве что лишние телодвижения при компиляции.

Comment: Все стандартно свелось к спору о личных предпочтениях, поскольку объективных аргументов ни у одной из сторон нет. Я считаю, что `emplace` нужно использовать по первоначальному предназначению, то есть именно для конструирования, а в прочих случая концептуально правильней `insert`. Вы считаете, что `emplace` нужно использовать всегда. Можно и так, и так, а компилятору вообще без разницы. Так что лучше всего зафиксировать разницу мнений и закончить. (Аргумент насчет библиотек совершенно мимо, кстати, это очень специфический случай. Там порой такая дичь встречается, но полностью обоснованная.)

Comment: @freim "личных предпочтениях" - личные предпочтения прозвучали пока **исключительно** с вашей стороны. То, что `emplace` является более общей, а `push` и `insert` зачастую реализуются через нее и не дают ничего, кроме потенциального оверхеда, - это факт.

Comment: Ну вы тоже свои предпочтения не обосновали ничем кроме "так надо". И насчет "более общей" - это не факт, а полная ерунда. Ничего не имею против ваших личных предпочтений, но все же не их выдавать за великие истины.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
    std::vector<int> vect;
    auto it = vect.insert(vect.end(), 5);
    it = vect.insert(vect.end(), 980);
```

Проверял в студии, работоспособно.

Comment: А зачем во второй строке вы получаете итератор, который в следующей же строке перезаписываете?

Comment: @freim пример, не более. Добавили - сразу получили.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator vector_push_back(std::vector<T> &vec, const T & data)
{
    vec.push_back(data);

    return vec.end() - 1;
}


int main()
{

  std::vector<int>v{1,2,3,4};

  auto it = vector_push_back(v, 5);

}
```

Comment: ну это как-то совсем брутально:)

а вот `.end() - 1` - это дело, я не стал так писать, потому что был не уверен, можно ли с конечного итератора так назад двигаться

Comment: @Zhihar: Двигаться, разумеется, можно.